# Where is the Monotouch Dialog UI Picker Element?

Tags: view, dialog, xamarin.ios, xamarin, picker

Wheres the custom picker element for monotouch dialog (Xamarin.IOS)?

// update

UIPickerView would be a wonderful element to have as a monotouch dialog element along with UIActionSheet.

Instead I journeyed into building one by hand and then attempted to fit it into an UIActionSheet.  Was couple of days work (I'm a noob) but got stuck trying to clean up the aesthetics of it (think I'll just stick with a 'ok' solution of embedding the picker inside a table for now).

Just in case anyone else embarks on this adventure here's a link to make your picker:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXa9WZMcmoE

Here's a link to how to setup a UIActionSheet: 
http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/UIActionSheet-Presenting-action-sheet-clipped-by-its-superview-warning-td3897607.html

// another update

Although not a custom picker element using MT.D, you can sort of have a popup picker by linking the input view of a control (view object i.e. text field) and set it's input view property to the picker.  The picker slides in from bottom whenever you click this control.  Think I just have to implement a custom view with my own picker and a cancel button somewhere...hmmmm:

http://nomtek.com/tips-for-developers/working-with-pickers/

Answer (score 1):

Your update is correct - you'll want to create a custom MT.D element that inherits from EntryElement, override the method that creates the UITextField and set the field's InputView to an input view of your choice.  I actually just wrote a tutorial on this: [Custom MT.D Input View & Element](http://www.adabrasoftware.com/post/Custom-Input-Views-with-MonoTouchDialog)